# How to set the weight of tf.slim with a numpy array

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I would like to show my example below:

```
x = tf.placeholder(dtype=...)
a = numpy.asarray([784, 10])
z = slim.fully_connected(x, 10, weights_initializer=?)
```

I have tried weights_initializer = lambda x1:a, it reports the error: TypeError: () got an unexpected keyword argument 'dtype'

I also found another post here:https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4016

However, I still don't know the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I don't really understand what you're trying to do. 
If your fully connected layer has 10 hidden neurons then your initializer must have the shape `(input_shape, 10)`, what you're giving is a `(2,)` shape. Secondly, to initialize weights with a constant matrix you should use `tf.constant_initializer(..)` function. 
Are you trying to do the following: (you can change the init function used with numpy)

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

slim = tf.contrib.slim

input_size = ?

x = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[input_size])
a = np.random.normal((input_size, 10))

z = slim.fully_connected(x, 10, 
weights_initializer=tf.constant_initializer(a))

init  = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

Comment: SOrry, I was planning to say a = numpy.random.random([784, 10]). Sorry, You answer is correct.